# How to calculate distance to point when there is an obstacle in the way?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm writing a genetic algorithm program where "cells" have to make their way to a point that is located behind an obstacle that they have to get to. The structure looks something like this

```
        target

  ---------------------

       cell pool
```

where the cells come from the pool and have to get around the obstacle and make their way to the target. My question is how I should go about calculating the distance from a cell to the target? I need this because I am going to dynamically color the closest cell each frame. My guess would be to essentially find the closest edge of the obstacle (left or right side) and draw a line to that, then bee line it to the target, and add the lengths of those two lines together, but I was wondering if there was a more optimal way.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you know the coordinates of the target, the cell, and the obstacle, you can stitch together two straight lines to get the distance, right? Or do you have more complicated obstacles in the way?

Comment: Right now it's static, but the obstacle will move left to right eventually. Probably should have stated that in the OP, my apologies.

Comment: I assume that that doesn't change the calculation now that I think of it though, because I'll still have all that info frame-by-frame.

Comment: Ok, so I would just make two calculations. 1. $d_1=$ distance from cell to LHS of obstacle + distance from LHS of obstacle to target. 2. $d_2=$ distance from cell to RHS of obstacle + distance from RHS of obstacle to target. Then you would write $d=\min(d_1, d_2).$

Comment: Appreciate the help @AdrianKeister!

Comment: Oh, one more thing you should do: check if the obstacle really is in the way. The orientation of the obstacle will be crucial here. Without more context, I'm not sure I can help you with that. Maybe calculate the intersection of the staight line between cell and target with the line segment representing the obstacle. If you get a solution, then the obstacle is in the way, and proceed as above. Otherwise, use the straight-line distance between the cell and the target.

Comment: Yeah, I believe it's pretty simple to do in this case. The window is a static size so I can just check if the cell is obstructed based on whether or not it is above the obstacle, which I believe is the only time a cell will not be obstructed at all (the obstacle will not move up/down). At least that's my understanding of it.

Comment: Will the target and cell always start right above each other?

Comment: Yes, every generation everything is reset exactly how it was the previous generation, so everything starts the same and moves the same way every time (other than the cells obviously). The pool and the target are static.

Comment: All right, sounds like you've got it!

Comment: If you want to handle multiple obstacles someday, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_shortest_path and http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.47.2037